# Iterate range of addresses between two IPV6 addresses

Tags: c, iteration, ipv6

I need some way to iterate over the range of addresses between two IPv6 addresses. i.e. if the first IP is `2a03:6300:1:103:219:5bff:fe31:13e1` and the second one is `2a03:6300:1:103:219:5bff:fe31:13f4`, I would like to visit the 19 addresses in that range.

With IPv4 I just do `inet_aton` for string representation and get `htonl` of `s_addr` in the resulting struct, but how can I do that for IPv6?

For simplify:

```
struct in6_addr sn,en;
long i;

s="2a03:6300:1:103:219:5bff:fe31:13e1";
e="2a03:6300:1:103:219:5bff:fe31:13f4";

inet_pton(AF_INET6,s,&sn);
inet_pton(AF_INET6,e,&en);
```

[..]

```
for (i = _first_ipv6_representation; i<=_second_ipv6_representation; i++){
    /* stuck here */
}
```

Comment: You have two questions in your question, they appear unrelated, and I am having trouble understanding exactly what you'd like to do.

Comment: Only one question: how to do "for" cycle iteration between 2 ipv6-addresses?

Comment: As in you'd like to store both `s` and `e` in something you can loop over? Or do you want to compare the two addresses?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: yes, I'd like to store both `s` and `e` in something I can loop over

Comment: just curious what you're using this for. This loop could run a *long time* depending on the input. ;-)

Comment: @Mike: for a search engine parsing proxy-server that have a lot of IPv6 binded IPs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old answer stricken per your comments, updated to iterate a range of addresses:

```
char output[64];
struct in6_addr sn, en;
int octet;

s="2a03:6300:1:103:219:5bff:fe31:13e1";
e="2a03:6300:1:103:219:5bff:fe31:13f4";

inet_pton(AF_INET6,s,&sn);
inet_pton(AF_INET6,e,&en);

for ( ; ; ) {
    /* print the address */
    if (!inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &sn, output, sizeof(output))) {
        perror("inet_ntop");
        break;
    }

    printf("%s\n", output);

    /* break if we hit the last address or (sn > en) */
    if (memcmp(sn.s6_addr, en.s6_addr, 16) >= 0) break;

    /* increment sn, and move towards en */
    for (octet = 15; octet >= 0; --octet) {
        if (sn.s6_addr[octet] < 255) {
            sn.s6_addr[octet]++;
            break;
        } else sn.s6_addr[octet] = 0;
    }

    if (octet < 0) break; /* top of logical address range */
}
```

Comment: no, you don't understand, i need to iterate between all addresses in range (i.e. from first ip to second)

Answer (score 3):

It's tricky indeed (I like this question). Basically you need to increment and compare integers that are stored like this: `uint8_t s6_addr[16]`.

- Find a cool way to convert those arrays to 128b integers and work from that
- Define two functions `inc_s6` and `cmp_s6` that increment / compare such arrays

Here is an attempt at `inc_s6`:

```
void inc_s6(uint8_t *addr)
{
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (++addr[i])
                    break;
        }
}
```

The compare function is a lot easier.

Comment: Since arithmetic in `uint8_t` is performed modulo 256, you can simply do `if (++addr[i]) break;` as the loop body.

Comment: @caf Right. I forgot that unsigned integer overflow is defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification:

I'm using that for some proxy-server that have a lot of binded IPv6 and to delegate new IP for each request.

My increment function with some additional explanation:

```
const char *s="2a03:6300:2:200:0:0:0:1"; // first ip in range

struct in6_addr sn;

inet_pton(AF_INET6,s,&sn);

static struct in6_addr cn = sn; //current ip in6_addr struct

unsigned int skipBits=126;
unsigned __int128 icn,skip; // works only with gcc

if (skipBits!=0){ // now we need to skip netmask bits to get next ip
    skip=pow(2,(128-skipBits))-2;
    u_int32_t swap;
    swap=ntohl(cn.s6_addr32[3]);
    cn.s6_addr32[3]=ntohl(cn.s6_addr32[0]);
    cn.s6_addr32[0]=swap;
    swap=ntohl(cn.s6_addr32[2]);
    cn.s6_addr32[2]=ntohl(cn.s6_addr32[1]);
    cn.s6_addr32[1]=swap;

    memcpy(&icn,&cn,sizeof icn);
    // increment, works very fast because gcc will compile it into sse2 intrinsic (double int64 operations)
    icn+=skip;
    memcpy(&cn,&icn,sizeof icn);

    swap=ntohl(cn.s6_addr32[3]);
    cn.s6_addr32[3]=ntohl(cn.s6_addr32[0]);
    cn.s6_addr32[0]=swap;
    swap=ntohl(cn.s6_addr32[2]);
    cn.s6_addr32[2]=ntohl(cn.s6_addr32[1]);
    cn.s6_addr32[1]=swap;
}
```

I don't show compare function because @sixlettervariables solution works good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Python3:

```
import ipaddress
st_add=int(ips.ip_address(st_add).packed.hex(),16)
end_add=int(ips.ip_address(end_add).packed.hex(),16)
Ips=set(ips.ip_address(ip).compressed for ip in range(st_add,end_add))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).